# Google Admin SDK return code for delete member call when invoked with non-member memberKey value

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Did Google recently change the return code sent to clients when the [delete member call](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/delete) is invoked with a `memberKey` parameter that does not represent a current member of the group from `404 Not Found` to `400 Bad Request`?

I tested using the Admin SDK Explorer found at this page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/delete . I used the group's email address as the groupKey and a user's (non-member) email address as the memberKey.

If so what is the best way for developers to become aware of such changes?

Comment: @chemdt I edited to explain I used the Admin SDK Explorer to verify the behavior I am seeing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Scouring the Admin SDK reference returned no results for error/response code definitions. This is a serious missing feature of the documentation. I'm unsure how Google expects developer to handle errors when we can't know what the errors will be.

That said, I receive a `404 Not Found` when invoking a groups.list call with an invalid `memberKey`. A `400 Bad Request` sounds like the structure of the call is at fault based on a description of that error code for the [Analystics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors). Could you post the code for your API call?

In response to your edit: It appears that the delete member call expects a user that is a current member of the groupKey group. If you are getting the same result (400 Bad Request) using the SDK Explorer then I guess that means the response code changed. If the Explorer gives you a 404 Not Found response, then it is likely a syntax error in your request code.